# what is the code for getting auth code from azure in IBM BPM

Tags: azure, rest, ibm-bpm

I am trying to create rest request using Call Multipart form data REST API service in REST API toolkit. It requires apiURL, HTTPHEADER, PARAMETERtoPOST, httpMethod (using GET). I defined all the parameters(client id, client secret, response type (code), scope and response mode (query)) and httpheader - > Content -Type is application/x-www-form-urlencoded.

But in the response message I dont get the authcode even though when I create whole URL directly including parameters , I get the authcode but without Redirect URI. If I include redirect uri, it shows me that URI is not configured even though system admin for that showed me its configured.
So am I missing any parameters or anything else?

Comment: Have you tried in Postman? Always the best place to start.

Comment: what help will postman do?

Comment: It will help you get the calls correct before moving to code. Just easier to visualize, etc. Merely a tip, not a solution.

Comment: You can refer to [BM BPM Rest API Authentication](https://www.ibm.com/mysupport/s/question/0D50z000062kkU5CAI/ibm-bpm-rest-api-authentication?language=en_US), [Tutorial: Creating an invoke REST API definition](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/acfc?topic=endpoint-tutorial-creating-invoke-rest-api-definition) and [Tutorial: Securing an API by using OAuth 2.0](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/acfc?topic=endpoint-tutorial-securing-api-by-using-oauth-20)